# Executar um SELECT dentro de um IF no SQL?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Gostaria de saber como executar uma condição IF com SELECT, ainda estou estudando sobre SQL por isso no exemplo irei tentar passar apenas a ideia pois a sintaxe provavelmente não estará correta.

```
IF (SELECT * FROM tb_ticker WHERE Ticker = '{$variavelPHP}')          //se a variável que é uma string for exatamente igual a um campo da coluna Ticker
   SELECT * FROM tb_ticker WHERE Ticker = '{$variavelPHP}'            //ela irá me retornar ele mesmo, o valor exato
ELSE
   SELECT * FROM tb_ticker WHERE Ticker LIKE '%{$variavelPHP}%' 
   OR Empresa LIKE '%{$variavelPHP}%' ORDER BY Ticker ASC LIMIT 20    //senão ele irá me retornar os possíveis nomes que podem estar em 2 colunas da mesma tabela ordenado pela coluna Ticker com limite de 20 campos
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar `EXISTS` em conjunto com outro filtros.

Exemplo:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tb_ticker 
 WHERE ((EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tb_ticker WHERE Ticker = '{$variavelPHP}')
   AND Ticker = '{$variavelPHP}')
    OR (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tb_ticker WHERE Ticker = '{$variavelPHP}') 
   AND (Ticker LIKE '%{$variavelPHP}%' 
    OR Empresa LIKE '%{$variavelPHP}%')))
 ORDER BY Ticker ASC LIMIT 20;
```

Veja rodando [aqui](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b903c/4).